# React Native BackAndroid fires twice at the 3rd route

Tags: react-native, navigator

I have three routes: Main.js,Detail.js,Page.js

In both detail.js and page.js, I have added the following codes:

```
constructor(props){
this.backAndroidHandler = this.backAndroidHandler.bind(this);}

componentDidMount(){
BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',this.backAndroidHandler);}

componentWillUnmount(){
BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress',this.backAndroidHandler);}

backAndroidHandler(){
if (this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length >1){
  this.props.navigator.pop();
  return true;
}
return false;}
```

When I click back button on Detail.js, it goes back to Main.js smoothly, however, when I click back on Page.js, it firstly go to Detail.js and then automatically to redirect to Main.js.

How should I fix it?

Comment: @BurakKarasoy No need to remove Listener?

Comment: seems it is  needed